# Swift_TransportException Cannot send message without a sender address when trying to send a notification to user that are been registered

Tags: laravel

I am trying to send a notification to a user that he has been registered using mailtrap.io, I entered the `MAIL_USERNAME` and `MAIL_PASSWORD` in the `config/mail.php` but I keep getting this error.
this is my config/mail.php

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=my username
MAIL_PASSWORD=my password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=my email address
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I am getting this error

```
Swift_TransportException
Cannot send message without a sender address
http://127.0.0.1:8000/register
```

Comment: You can provide a detailed description of the error you have, to get a response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.6 Notifications "Cannot send message without a sender address"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60249537/laravel-5-6-notifications-cannot-send-message-without-a-sender-address)

Comment: @DarrylE.Clarke no it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely missing the `MAIL_FROM` or `MAIL_FROM_NAME` environment variables in you `.env` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

MAIL_FROM=example@test.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Imnotperson"
```

Comment: I filled the MAIL_FROM and MAIL_FROM_NAME variable with my email address but still nothing

Comment: Did you run `php artisan config:clear` or `php artisan config:cache` to either clear or re-cache your config files?

Comment: OK. 1) Can you post the content of your `config/mail.php`? 2) Have you been modifying that file directly or via your `.env` file? 3) If you `dd(config('mail'))` what does it output?

Comment: I posted the content above, I tried ```dd(config(mail))``` in my registerController but no output. just the same error I'm having

Comment: I tried modifying the file directly and via the ```.env`` file

Comment: Can you add the exact error message you are getting to your question? If you are unable to get `dd()` to work, you've got a bigger issue than i thought!

Answer (score 0):

For gmail(laravel 8).

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=username@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=gmailpasswordhere
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Make sure you grant the necessary permissions. Find the Please allow less reliable apps option and enable it.

https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/UnlockCaptcha